# Excel shows different files in same window

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel

In Firefox, I downloaded an Excel spreadsheet and it displayed a dialog box asking what to do with it, so I selected "Open in Excel".  Then I downloaded another Excel spreadsheet and opened that one in Excel as well.  My taskbar shows 2 Excel icons, but there's only one Excel window.  When I use the taskbar to switch between the spreadsheets, each one replaces the other in the Excel window.  How can I get 2 Excel windows - one for each spreadsheet?

I am running Windows 7 with Excel 2010.

Answer (score 1):

You should open as much as you want Excel instances (i.e. by clicking on it's icon on the Desktop) and then use File-Open command instead of direct opening spreadsheet right from the browser.

Comment: This is not ideal because I don't intend on keeping these spreadsheets and I'd have to remember to delete them when I'm done.

Comment: Agree with you, @pacoverflow, but alas there is no (or I don't know maybe) another way to do that. Excel since early 2000's up to 2010 version implements MDI (multiple document interface),but without ability of rearrange opened sheet windows within application window. Requests like your was very demanded feature so MS returns SDI (single document interface) functionality  in MS Office 2013.

Comment: I just tried opening 2 spreadsheets from Windows Explorer, and I have the same problem.  I see 2 Excel icons in the taskbar, but they both occupy the same Excel window.

Comment: Opening spreadsheet from Explorer does _exactly the same_ thing as opening downloaded excel file from Firefox. Again, you should start two instances of Excel _application_ by clicking it's icon, not the spreadsheet icon. Hope this helps ;-)